# Get all database actions (insert, update , delete, alter, ...)information 

Tags: sql-server-2008

in sql server 2008 is there a way to get the user that inserted some rows, or updated, deleted, dropped, altered some tables?
can we get this information the date that occurred?

also is there a way to know if the data was inserted from the same machine or from other machine?

Edit: if it's really hard then maybe a way to achieve this is to user triggers
but is there a way to catch every action that happens on the DB so i can log them all??
something like **on insert on any table**

i want everything to be done on the DB so no matter what business app i use it will be logged

Comment: Either use some sort of log or add a column to the data with the info you want.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you already had something set up in advance - a CDC mechanism of some kind it is going to be incredibly difficult to extract that information from the logs. It is possible given enough time, but it is a highly skilled forensic activity that is extremely time consuming to perform. (And relies on full logs being available.) There are third party log readers than can help with this but it will still be a huge effort.